# Angular load scripts, css specyfic to pages

Tags: angularjs

I have a `index.html` page where I download some common js/css. On one page page, when navigated through ui-router , I want to download page specyfic scripts, for instance libraries that are required for this page. This markup is included in XHR HTML returned when I navigate to a view:

```
<link href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

CSS gets downloaded but I see no JavaScript request on the network tab. How can I fix it / what is the proper way to handling this situation?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Regarding requirejs: usually on production you still use optimizer and you bundle everything into one file right? I don't want to use it: I want to really defer downloading some stuff until needed.

Comment: https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/getting-started